# Pandas DataFrame from re.findall list

Tags: python, pandas

How do I create a `pandas DataFrame` from a `re.findall` list?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

directory = "/Folder/on/Drive/"

docs = os.listdir(directory)
for filename in docs:
    if filename.lower().endswith(".pdf"):
        match = re.findall("\D{2}\d{10}", filename)
    df = pd.DataFrame(match, columns=["Match"])
    df.to_csv(directory + "match.csv", index=False, delimiter=",")
```

The above will only write the last result in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On every iteration through your filenames you are creating/overwriting your csv file.  Move your dataframe creation outside the loop and create a list to track all your filenames that match your regex:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import re

directory = "/Folder/on/Drive/"

docs = os.listdir(directory)
match=[]
for filename in docs:
    if filename.lower().endswith(".pdf"):
        match.extend(re.findall("\D{2}\d{10}", filename))
df = pd.DataFrame(match, columns=["Match"])
df.to_csv(directory + "match.csv", index=False, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thanks, the indentation was actually not the problem because I had tried that already (it was right in my code, wrong when copied it into StackExchange). But what helped me was using `match.extend(re.findall(`.